# What does もっとたゆたゆver. mean in AT-X shows' broadcast information?

Tags: anime-production, japanese-language, nande-koko-ni-sensei-ga

NSFW Warning: The anime mentioned below is something that I think would qualify as borderline hentai or close to something like hentai.

Anyway, I came across this manga called *Nande Koko ni Sensei ga!?* which I found out just now that it will have an anime adaptation. From [here](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2019-03-08/why-the-hell-are-you-here-teacher-anime-2nd-promo-video-reveals-april-7-premiere/.144333), it says that Tokyo MX, BS11 and AT-X will air it starting on April 07.

Visiting [AT-X's site](https://www.at-x.com/program/detail/10750), however, shows this information:

> - 放送スケジュール
> - もっとたゆたゆver.
> - 2019年4月11日（木）スタート
> - 毎週（木）21：45
> - 毎週（土）13：45
> - 毎週（火）29：45
> - 【15分×1話】
> - ※視聴年齢制限あり※

From what I could understand here from the little knowledge I have of Japanese, 4月11日 would mean April 11 as the start of broadcast, contrary to April 07. The times would be the broadcast schedules on specific days per week and 視聴年齢制限あり seems to be something about age restriction. What's bugging me is the line 'もっとたゆたゆver.' If I understand correctly, it is read as 'motto tayutayu' where 'motto' would mean more. But I can't seem to find anything about what たゆたゆ means.

What does the line もっとたゆたゆver. mean on AT-X shows' broadcast information?

Comment: I think it is refering to a Hentai named Tayu Tayu by Yamatogawa, I think they mean something like more lewdness?! https://myanimelist.net/anime/19631/Tayu_Tayu

Comment: I also came across that hentai while searching but I could not see how this phrase refers to this particular hentai. It's not licensed by AT-X nor was it aired on their website and the authors are different so I see no connection between the two. I also could not find any translation at all for the phrase 'Tayu Tayu.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tayu-tayu" is an [onomatopoeia](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-onomatopoeia/) word. Characteristics of a Japanese onomatopoeia include a two-syllable word in a repeated fashion. Many, if not all of these translated poorly into English. For an example fuwa-fuwa can be used to the fluffy texture of something (tangible or intangible, like a mood or figurative characteristic). They tend to be more sporadic, with little to no clear standard of usage (so they tend to be quite informal, generally), used a bit like pewpew, kaboom, pow, in a loose sense.

"Tayu-tayu" despite being the title of a popularly known explicit hentai anime and manga, it is in no way related to that series. Typically, it can be used to describe the swaying or shaking motion. It's likely derived from "tayuta", which [can refer](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%86%E3%81%9F) to something tangible like water, or something intangible like anxiety (like fluttering of the heart/mind). As with many things in Japanese, the context is very important to the actual meaning. In this case the AT-X version, is likely referring to the more "uncensored" nature of the broadcast, as for what is doing the "swaying"... you'll have to watch to find out.

Comment: [AT-X rated it as R15+](https://www.at-x.com/whats_new/detail/4953?category=anonymous), and it'd most possibly be the uncensored version of [this PV with mysterious light-beam](https://youtu.be/nVj-aQD2ArY)